# Nodemailer SMTP not working on production server

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer, dotenv

I am having issues sending email via nodemailer - SMTP(from another host) on production

i uploaded my API on a server(Scaleway Dev), i'm using Ubuntu Bionic and while testing noticed it is not sending emails(which i need for verification of a user).

at first i thought the request isn't getting to the server, but when i tried logging in i got a "confirm your password" response, i check the mongoDB database and the user is there, but still no confirmation email.

I tried checking it on localhost, thinking it might be the dotenv dependency, but it works there, what gives?

node version on my server is **8.10.0**
and on my personal computer **11.12.0**

these are my dependencies

```
    enter code here
    "dependencies": {

    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parse": "^0.1.0",
    "client-sessions": "^0.8.0",
    "connect": "^3.6.6",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.1",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.8",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "session": "^0.1.0",
    "session-mongoose": "^0.5.2"
}
```

these options used are specified by the host that i'm using

```
//this is my transporter constant

    const transporter   = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: '*different host from the server*',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: my used email(hardcoded),
        pass: process.env.EMAILPASS
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

//my email options

    let mailOptions ={
                from: '"Company Name <noreply@*different host DNS*>',
                to: req.body.email,
                subject: *subject*
                html: `Email Content with confirmation token`
            }

//emailing the message itself

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
                if(err){
                    return console.log(err);
                }
                console.log("message sent");
            });
```

i'm using this email generator(https://generator.email/) for fast throwaway emails. the mailing starts after i save the user.

I'm perplexed as to what should i do... any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had issues with nodemailer in the past. I'm using mailgun (https://www.mailgun.com/) to send my emails. They offer 10,000 emails a month for free. Here is a code that works with mailgun:

dependencies:

```
"express": "4.16.4",
"config": "3.0.1",
"nodemailer": "5.1.1",
"nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "1.4.0"
```

code (it is wrapped inside an express router) :

```
const config = require('config');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mg = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    //the data has to be an array. It will send as many emails as the number of items in the array
    var emailsList = ["test@test.com"];
    emailsList[0].name = "Test Name";

    var auth = {
        auth: {
            api_key: config.get('mailgunApiKey'),
            domain: config.get('mailgunDomain')
        }
    };

    transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(auth)),
    EmailTemplate = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate,
    path = require('path'),
    Promise = require('bluebird');

    function sendEmail (obj) {
        return transporter.sendMail(obj);
    }

    function loadTemplate (templateName, contexts) {
        let template = new EmailTemplate(path.join(__dirname, '../templates', templateName));
        return Promise.all(contexts.map((context) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                template.render(context, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    else resolve({
                        email: result,
                        context,
                    });
                });
            });
        }));
    }

    loadTemplate('dailyReferralEmail', emailsList).then((results) => {
        return Promise.all(results.map((result) => {
            sendEmail({
                to: result.context.email,
                from: 'Your Name <your-email@test.com>',
                'h:Reply-To': 'your-email@test.com',
                subject: result.email.subject,
                html: result.email.html,
                text: result.email.text,
            });
        }));
    }).then(() => {

        var response = {
            text: "Email sent"
        }
        JSON.stringify(response);
        res.status(200).send(response);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

As a template generator, I'm using HBS. So you must have a templates folder in the root folder of your project, with this tree:

[image]

You can use your variables inside your email with {{ }}.

Inside html.hbs:

```
<p>Hello {{name}}</p>
```

Inside subject.hbs

```
Subject of your email
```

Inside text.hbs

```
Preview text of your email
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: does mail gun have the ability to have a custom email address? like noreply@companyname.com

Comment: @Yoshy yes of course :) you just need to verify the domain by entering some DNS TXT entries in your domain registrar. Mailgun will explain you everything

Comment: Sounds great, i'll definetely check it out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Yoshy No problem! If my answer satisfies you, you can upvote it and mark it as the answer to your problem ;)

Comment: actually decided to go with mailgun, becouse of DKIM settings, never been happier.

Comment: Rather than giving solution/help, you gave alternative.
Seems like a planned promotional QnA to me :P